# WordPress Get Number of Post + all Number of all Posts (example No. 3 of 19 Posts)

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to show the actual number of a post + all like: „No. 3 of 19 Posts“.

I've tried with – it shows all posts but I don't how I show the current post number.

```
No. {POST NUMER} of <?php $count_posts = wp_count_posts(); echo $count_posts->publish; ?> Posts
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is inside a `wp_query`, you can do:

```
echo $wp_query->current_post+1;
```

Source: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20789/print-current-post-index-number-within-loop

If not, I think you would need to explain Wordpress what exactly do you mean by "post number" - that is by which criteria should it be counted. For that, you would probably need to reconstruct `wp_query` with $args relevant to you (e.g. `post_status => publish`). Although maybe there is some builtin way I don't know about.

### Edit

This is untested:

```
/** Your current post id*/
$curr_id = get_the_ID();

/** Your posts query */
$args = ('post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'this depends on you'); // ... and all other args you would need
$posts = get_posts($args);
$posts_count = count($posts);
for ($i=0;$i<$posts_count;$i++) {
    if ($posts[$i]->ID === $curr_id) {
          $current_post_num = $i;
          break;
    }
}

echo "No. $current_post_num of $posts_count Posts";
```

---

Some tips:

- Use Google more! "get current post number wordpress" brought me straight to Wordpress Stack Exchange question mentioned above.
- Post similar questions to [Wordpress Stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), the odds for you getting your answer would simply be higher.

Comment: most likely he'll need to make $wp_query available first - `global $wp_query;`. Also, if he's using pagination, that needs to be accounted for. Relevant values can be found in that same $wp_query object.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would like to use on every single post page. The user would see: This is No. 3 of 19 posts.

Comment: @l00per: Consider to edit your question with that information. 

In this case, you would probably need to reconstruct `wp_query` as mentioned in my answer.

@MSTannu: Exactly!

Comment: If this is in a single post page, your task is much harder. Posts are not "numbered" like that. You could do this by using `get_posts` to get all posts that match your system of counting them and then looping through the results to determine which ID matches your current post.

Comment: Okay thank you – I thought it's a simple task. I've <?php echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->get_queried_object(); ?> as well – but no luck.